# R: How to bind two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, bind

I have two data sets import from csv files.

```
str(ssh)
'data.frame':   80000 obs. of  1 variable:
$ x: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

str(latlon)
'data.frame':   80000 obs. of  2 variables:
$ lat: num  -24.9 -24.6 -24.4 -24.1 -23.9 ...
$ lon: num  30.1 30.1 30.1 30.1 30.1 ...
```

i need to make single data frame as follows

```
lat    lon    x

-24.9   30.1   NA
```

Comment: `cbind(latlon, ssh)` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this is a basic task for `cbind`:

```
cbind(latnon, ssh)
```

---

You have used the term "bind". This can be used to guide your learning of relevant R functions if you use the right tools.

For example, try the following and see what happens:

```
apropos("bind")
??"bind"
```

In both of the above, you would have several options to explore further that would guide you closer to the relevant functions you would require.